# Extracting Headings and paragraphs separately from xml files in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, extract

I first converted the xml file to a string and then tried searching for specific tags in the file. However, the string files are incredibly long (about 1.5 billion characters), so the search often takes a few minutes to just count how many headings there are. Is there a better way to do this? Or a set method for extracting data.

Comment: why are you converting xml file to string... you can use any of SAX (or) DOM parser to read heading tags from xml file

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert XML to string.

Parse the XML and extract required data using XPATH (address of tag in XML)
For details, refer [this site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)